# Loading a 64-bit Windows PE file from memory

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, portable-executable

I wanted to load a Windows PE file (a.k.a. EXE) from a memory buffer in C++ so I found [this](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/43043-64bit-pe-loader) code. Using a simple hello world example, it works fine. However, when loading a more sophisticated EXE with static dependencies the code crashes instead of loading the PE file successfully. My updated PE loader code is the following:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdexcept>

inline auto fix_image_iat(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header, PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt_header)
{
    auto import_table = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR>(nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].
            VirtualAddress + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(dos_header));

    const DWORD iat_loc = nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT].VirtualAddress ?
        IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT : IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT;

    const DWORD iat_rva = nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[iat_loc].VirtualAddress;
    const SIZE_T iat_size = nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[iat_loc].Size;

    const auto iat = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(iat_rva + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(dos_header));
    DWORD op;
    VirtualProtect(iat, iat_size, PAGE_READWRITE, &op);

    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA thunk;
    while (import_table->Name)
    {
        const auto import_base = LoadLibraryA(
            reinterpret_cast<LPCSTR>(import_table->Name + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(dos_header)));
        auto fix_up = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA>(import_table->FirstThunk + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(
            dos_header));
        if (import_table->OriginalFirstThunk)
        {
            thunk = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA>(import_table->OriginalFirstThunk + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(dos_header));
        }
        else
        {
            thunk = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA>(import_table->FirstThunk + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(dos_header));
        }

        while (thunk->u1.Function)
        {
            if (thunk->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG64)
            {
                fix_up->u1.Function =
                    reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(GetProcAddress(import_base, reinterpret_cast<LPCSTR>(thunk->u1.Ordinal & 0xFFFF)));

            }
            else
            {
                const PCHAR func_name = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME>(thunk->u1.AddressOfData)->Name + reinterpret_cast<
                    UINT_PTR>(dos_header);
                fix_up->u1.Function = reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(GetProcAddress(import_base, func_name));
            }
            fix_up++;
            thunk++;
        }
        import_table++;
    }
}

inline auto map_image_to_memory(const char* pe_buffer)
{
    auto raw_image_base = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(pe_buffer);

    if (IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE != raw_image_base->e_magic)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(("Invalid DOS signature"));
    }

    auto nt_header = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS>(raw_image_base->e_lfanew + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(raw_image_base));
    if (IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE != nt_header->Signature)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(("Invalid NT header"));
    }
    
    if (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 != nt_header->FileHeader.Machine)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(("Not a 64-bit module"));
    }
    
    if (nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR].VirtualAddress)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error((".NET is not supported"));
    }

    auto section_header = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER>(raw_image_base->e_lfanew + sizeof * nt_header
            + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(raw_image_base));

    auto mem_image_base = VirtualAlloc(reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(nt_header->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
        nt_header->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    if (mem_image_base == nullptr)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(("VirtualAlloc() failed"));
    }

    memcpy(mem_image_base, raw_image_base, nt_header->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders);

    for (WORD section_index = 0; section_index < nt_header->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; section_index++)
    {
        memcpy(reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(section_header->VirtualAddress + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(mem_image_base)),
            reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(section_header->PointerToRawData + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(raw_image_base)),
            section_header->SizeOfRawData);
        section_header++;
    }
    
    return static_cast<PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(mem_image_base);
}

//works with manually mapped files
HANDLE GetImageActCtx(HMODULE module)
{
    WCHAR temp_path[MAX_PATH];
    WCHAR temp_filename[MAX_PATH];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        HRSRC resource_info = FindResource(module, MAKEINTRESOURCE(i), RT_MANIFEST);
        if (resource_info) {
            HGLOBAL resource = LoadResource(module, resource_info);
            DWORD resource_size = SizeofResource(module, resource_info);
            const PBYTE resource_data = (const PBYTE)LockResource(resource);
            if (resource_data && resource_size) {
                FILE* fp;
                errno_t err;
                DWORD ret_val = GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, temp_path);

                if (0 == GetTempFileName(temp_path, L"manifest.tmp", 0, temp_filename))
                    return NULL;

                err = _wfopen_s(&fp, temp_filename, L"w");

                if (errno)
                    return NULL;

                fprintf(fp, (const char *)resource_data);
                fclose(fp);
                break;
            }
            else {
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    ACTCTXW act = { sizeof(act) };
    act.lpSource = temp_filename;
    return CreateActCtx(&act);
}

BOOL FixImageRelocations(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header, PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt_header, ULONG_PTR delta)
{
    ULONG_PTR size;
    PULONG_PTR intruction;
    PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION reloc_block =
        (PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)(nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress +
            (UINT_PTR)dos_header);

    while (reloc_block->VirtualAddress) {
        size = (reloc_block->SizeOfBlock - sizeof(reloc_block)) / sizeof(WORD);
        PWORD fixup = (PWORD)((ULONG_PTR)reloc_block + sizeof(reloc_block));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++, fixup++) {
            if (IMAGE_REL_BASED_DIR64 == *fixup >> 12) {
                intruction = (PULONG_PTR)(reloc_block->VirtualAddress + (ULONG_PTR)dos_header + (*fixup & 0xfff));
                *intruction += delta;
            }
        }
        reloc_block = (PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)(reloc_block->SizeOfBlock + (ULONG_PTR)reloc_block);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void load_portable_executable(const char* pe_buffer)
{
    const auto dos_header = map_image_to_memory(pe_buffer);

    auto nt_header = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS>(dos_header->e_lfanew + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(dos_header));
    HANDLE actctx = NULL;
    UINT_PTR cookie = 0;
    BOOL changed_ctx = FALSE;
    if (nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE].VirtualAddress) {
        actctx = GetImageActCtx(reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(dos_header));
        if (actctx)
            changed_ctx = ActivateActCtx(actctx, &cookie);
    }
    
    fix_image_iat(dos_header, nt_header);

    if (nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress) {
        ptrdiff_t delta = (ptrdiff_t)((PBYTE)dos_header - (PBYTE)nt_header->OptionalHeader.ImageBase);
        if (delta)
            FixImageRelocations(dos_header, nt_header, delta);
    }
    
    // Calculate the absolute entry point address
    const auto entry_point_address = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(nt_header->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint + reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(dos_header));

    // Launch the PE file
    static_cast<void(*)()>(entry_point_address)(); // TODO Crashes here
}
```

Note that `C++20` is required to successfully compile.

Any idea why it crashes at the last line of code when passing control to the entry point address? Is there any library or clean reference implementation for PE loading (on Windows)?

[image]

Comment: What you are attempting to do is EXTREMELY difficult to accomplish. The OS Loader is complex, and you would have to replicate everything it does.  Best to not implement it manually, use a pre-existing library that does all of the hard work ([asking for recommendations is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), though). But why can't you simply save your memory buffer to a temp file and then execute it normally with `CreateProcess()`? Let the OS do its job.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I can save the PE file to a file and execute it the "conventional" way but it would be cooler and more secure to do it in-memory so the PE file never hits the disk. You're talking about using libraries instead, which one even has this functionality? It seems like I couldn't find a suitable library, only poorly developed code snippets or GitHub repositories.

Comment: *"the code crashes"* - Details required.

Comment: @IInspectable: I added the exception but it seems to be fairly meaningless

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza there is only one example of this I've seen working and it's not what I'd call 'nice' code and that's [chromium](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/master/sandbox/win/src) and even then making sense of this is not easy.

Comment: Don't post images when text can convey the same information. Please provide the exception information as text, alongside the call stack at the point the exception is raised. Make sure to load up symbol files to turn the call stack human readable.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a similar thing, loading an exe file (with LoadLibraryEx flag  LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL) into the address space of the loading application. In this way I can observe all the activities of the program from its inception.

The steps are:

1. LoadLibrary, and if successful then
2. Patch the IAT
3. Get the address of entry-point of the loaded program
4. CreateThread, CREATE_SUSPENDED with the thread-start-address being the address of entry-point.
5. ResumeThread and off she goes.

So far there are 2 types of files that can be loaded, those with relocation table and those without. The ones with the relocation table are the modern ones compiled with /DynamicBase and the older ones do not have this information.

I compiled the loader to have fixed-base address way above the default 0x140000000 for x64 to ensure that there is ample space below it for  loaded exes that have no relocation and have to be loaded at the default address.

The OS loader applies relocation fixups but does not fix import addresses which we have to do manually.

Any dll we load to fix the imports need no further cooking as the OS loader takes care of that.

Now just like the experience BullyWiiPlaza had I found some programs can be loaded and run perfectly yet many others crash on startup. And the annoying feature that when you exit your loaded program it tends to take with it the loading application on its way out.

To fix this I intercepted the CRT functions abort, _cexit, _c_exit and the kernel ExitProcess
and just the sheer virtue of using these functions enables the loaded program to go out alone but I use the opportunity to UnregisterClass in case I have to re-load the previous not so well written app.
Remember the RegisterClass function can fail with an error message ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS which isn't a sufficient reason to abort the application.

Another important function to intercept is GetModuleHandle because when the loaded app uses this function as GetModuleHandle(0) to query its base address then without intercepting it and returning its hModule the OS will give it the Loader's base address which will cause a crash.

What I find confusing is that some lost versions of my applications could load apps that have no relocation info and run successfully but after ceaseless tweaking I could no longer run them.

The problem appears to be write access violation.
So I checked the protection parameters given to VirtualProtect and found from this following code that the iat_size is small and does not include the thunk I wish modify.

DWORD iat_loc = (nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT].VirtualAddress)
? IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT : IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT;

UINT_PTR iat_rva = nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[iat_loc].VirtualAddress;

SIZE_T iat_size = nt_header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[iat_loc].Size;

LPVOID iat = (LPVOID)(iat_rva + (UINT_PTR)dos_header);

DWORD op;
VirtualProtect(iat, iat_size, PAGE_READWRITE, &op);

If anyone wants to recreate the problem then the specimen I used was Celemony Melodyne 5.
It does not have a relocation table and loads at address 0x140000000.

What is confusing is that other x64 applications such as DarkWave Studio run normally except it takes out the loader when it exits.

And by the way Microsoft has made a fine mess of the pragmas data_seg and data_section with respect to x64 altho they claim it works in the documentation.