# Executing a binary from inside memory

Tags: c++, node.js, c, bin

Basically, I'm looking for a way to execute a binary from inside node js. Usually, this is done by first writing the binary onto the disk. Then execute it from the shell. But this poses a lot of security risk as the binary can stay on the user's computer after execution. I tried using temp files but, they have the same security variabilities as regular files.

Someone told me about stubs and crypters which store the binary data encrypted that way it's not accessible until the file is executed. On execution, the data is decrypted and launched by injecting the binary into the process. This way the actual binary information doesn't stay on the system and the only time it's visible is during execution.

My problem is that I'm a node js dev. And have no idea how to do this. I know there are crypters online but they seem very suspect. The other problem is that they cant be easily scripted. Most of them are GUI-based. They also need a stub file that's written in c or c++, which I have little experience in.

In Node, you usually use child_processes then **execFile()** but this requires the file being written on disk first.

Comment: I'd say write it to disk in a temp location, execute it, then erase it when it's done running.  Or, find someone else who has written this for you on your OS.  Otherwise, you'll have to look into an OS-specific way to load a binary executable image from memory.  This won't be an nodejs-thing, this will be C/C++ level code interacting directly with memory and the OS.

Comment: Here's one reference to someone else trying (only partially successful) to do this on Windows: [Loading a 64-bit Windows PE file from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68988499/loading-a-64-bit-windows-pe-file-from-memory).

Comment: If you are concerned about security issues, you should not ever execute a native binary executable. If it is not run within a virtual machine (and I mean a real virtual machine, that emulates a processor and operating system, not some java script sandbox), a native executable has all the powers to do whatever it likes (store things on disk, execute root kits, shutdown the machine, register in autostart mechanisms, these kind of things)

Comment: You're right if the binary was the thing that posed the security issue. My problem is that the binary need to be secure. I'm not worried about the binary posing a security risk. After all i wrote the dam thing